# Word for person who became rich by cheating others

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word for a person who became rich by cheating others? I want to use it in formal language.

Comment: There will be a *lot* of words, none of which will be *the* correct answer. Voting to close as "not constructive".

Comment: [cheater](http://thesaurus.com/browse/cheater)--->[swindler](http://thesaurus.com/browse/swindler)

Comment: these words donot tell the person has become rich by cheating others I believe

Comment: In UK English, many people will understand calling someone a [Rachman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Rachman) to mean the person is being compared to "Britain's worst landlord", who became rich by charging extortionate rents (effectively, cheating his tenants).

Comment: tx @FumbleFingers

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Politician. :^)

Comment: 'robber baron' is one kind.

Comment: [shyster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shyster); professionally unscrupulous. -Your title might as well be the definition...

Comment: Con man is one possible word.